# jqplot does not work well in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7, jqplot

Got a series of question related to the compatibility issue of running JavaScript in IE7. I am using jqplot to generate figures, which works well in Chrome and IE8, but does not work in IE7.

To diagnose, I just run the simplest code `$.jqplot('chart1', s1)` and it works in IE7. So I think the problems are about all the options (except the legends). Can anyone give me some suggestion? Does IE7 only accept certain type of syntax?

CODE and [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/Htp2A/):

```
<div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:650px; height:400px;"></div>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://www.prioritymarketers.com/jqplot/src/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->​

<script>
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

var ms= 2
var s1 =[[5.0, 23.0, 131.0, 779.0, 4667.0, 27995.0, 167963.0, 1007771.0, 6046619.0, 36279707.0], [13.0, 85.0, 517.0, 3109.0, 18661.0, 111973.0, 671845.0, 4031077.0, 24186469.0, 145118821.0]]

L = [{label: 'Stage 1'}];

var i = 2
while (i <= ms) {
    L.push({label: 'Stage' + i});
    i++;
}

$.jqplot('chart1', s1, {

    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false,
        pointLabels: {
            show: false
        },
    },

    series: L,
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: 'Time units',
            pad: 0,
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: 'Number of individuals',
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            pad: 0
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        location: 'nw',
        placement: 'inside',
        fontSize: '11px'
    }
})
</script>
​
```

Comment: turn your options on one by one until it breaks :P

Comment: the Internet doesn't work well in IE7...

Comment: @jbabey:tested. only legend option works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that IE isn't a big fan when there are commas after the last element in a set of options.

**EXAMPLE:**

This:

```
 seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false,
        pointLabels: {
            show: false
        },
    },
```

Would become:

```
seriesDefaults: {
    showMarker: false,
    pointLabels: {
        show: false
    }},
```

A subtle difference, but it may or may not fix your issue.

Try changing your plot function to:

```
$.jqplot('chart1', s1, {

    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false,
        pointLabels: {
            show: false
        }
    },

    series: L,
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: 'Time units',
            pad: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: 'Number of individuals',
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            pad: 0
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        location: 'nw',
        placement: 'inside',
        fontSize: '11px'
    }
})
```

**Also**, last time I used excanvas I ended up having to make sure it was the latest release.

Link: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/downloads/list

Comment: Thank you! It is the ',' issue!

Comment: I had the same issue recently while using Flot. It was definitely a pain to figure out. Glad it helped! =)

Comment: Have you compared Jqplot and Flot or similar stuff like google plot?

Comment: I looked through numerous charting tools when starting my graphing project and settled on Flot due to its cost (free =) and based off requirements sent by the customer. Many helpful plugins and a decent community/threads for help were definitely factors as well.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://piwik.org/blog/2011/06/piwik-innovative-with-javascript-canvas-chart-and-contributing-by-jqplot-creator/)

> The canvas tag and jqPlot work well on most browsers. All canvas
>   features used by jqPlot are supported on Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+,
>   Chrome 8.0+, Opera 10+ and IE 9+. IE 6 – 8 are supported through
>   Google's excanvas.js library.

Do you have said `excanvas.js` library? More of the features would probably work if you did.

Comment: I have included "<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://www.prioritymarketers.com/jqplot/src/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->​" in my HTML. But it did not solve the problem...

Comment: if i were you i would be happy it works at all, the documentation clearly states that all features work on IE9+, not IE7

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Chase helped me to find that it was the comma issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with other version of IE for you ? I had similar issue but in my case it didnt work for IE7 and IE8 . I dont exactly remember how I fixed it .

If you check jquery.jqplot.js there is a line which make sure that versions less than IE9 uses excanvas.js

make sure that there is a line as following

```
 * > <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Else try to include files in this sequence

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../libs/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <!-- BEGIN: load jqplot -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jqplot/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js"></script>

  <!-- END: load jqplot -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will clean the beginning part of my code. In my case, the problem is caused by commas after the last element